# Fade effect when mouse over and out

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseout

I need to add Fade effect on mouseover and out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtchange").mouseover(function (){
        $('#txtchange').text("My New Txt");
    });
    $("#txtchange").mouseout(function (){
        $('#txtchange').text("Old Txt");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){    
       $("#txtchange").mouseover(function (){
           $("#txtchange").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).text("My New Txt").fadeIn();
           });
       });    
       $("#txtchange").mouseout(function (){
          $("#txtchange").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text("Old Txt").fadeIn();
          });   
       });    
  });
```

Comment: Works ! amzing thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `fadeIn()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtchange").mouseover(function (){
        $('#txtchange').text("My New Txt").fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
    $("#txtchange").mouseout(function (){
        $('#txtchange').text("Old Txt").fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
});
```